# Image not filling height of Div in Owl Carousel

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I'm lost on what I am missing here. I have this Owl Carousel set up [on this page](http://kimwilddesigns.com/responsive/index.htm). (Right now there are 3 of the same image as a placeholder)

When you reduce it to max-width: 768px, I am trying to get the image to fill the height of the 500px div (in red), while keeping the proportions, with anything else getting cut off. [image]

[CSS files are Here](http://kimwilddesigns.com/responsive/css/main.css)
[And here](http://kimwilddesigns.com/responsive/plugins/mobile-menu/mobile-menu-styles.css)

I know this is probably something simple I am missing, I just can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: You should add code to the question and not only links that will likely change once the issue is solved (making it impossible to reproduce the issue)

Comment: Hi yes I see some people do that and can do that, I'm just never sure what exact code pertains and feel like I would have to post the entire css file(s)

Comment: The code you linked to doesn't pertain to the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry then I don't know what code would - I linked to the html and all the css, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh I see I attached the wrong css, sorry about that, I see what you mean. I'm going to have to re-ask this question the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the following id/class to this?

```
 #owl-demo .item img {
 display: block;
 height: 500px;
```

Comment: Yes I did try that but is stretches the image vertically to fill the space, I am trying to get it to fill the height proportionately while clipping off any excess.

Comment: that's what it is doing for me...  kimwilddesigns.com/responsive/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl-carousel.css Line 17 changing `height:auto;` to your desired height will stretch the image vertically as well as horizontally and maintain the proportions while clipping excess horizontal width.

Comment: The thing is I want it to do this only on the media query for @media only screen and (max-width: 768px). It looks OK full screen, the problem is when I put the media query in at 768 to have a height of 500px that the image will not fill.